# How to implement SP list with this?

Tags: web-part, data-view-web-part, image-display

I found a nice article that talks about image rotating. I want to read the pictures from picture library. how would I do that ? http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a DataView web part for your Picture Library to your page using SharePoint Designer.
- Customize the XSL to reformat your output into the tags expected by the jQuery.
- Include the jQuery script and css file reference at the top of your page.
- Call the jQuery method using the example code you referenced in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Picture Library Slideshow Web Part built into SharePoint if you want a quick win. I think it's part of the 'Standard' or 'Enterprises' features Feature, but I'm not sure which one.